# Hooking a DLL function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, hook, delphi-6

I have a coclass which checks the registry to determine if an application is installed, but it does this poorly and doesn't find newer versions of the application.  In cases where a competing application has been installed, it will try to open that one.  If the competing application has been uninstalled, the program will crash.  This coclass is defined in a DLL file I do not have the source code for the library, so I can't just change that.  I have been looking into using hooking to replace the function with one that works, but it seems complicated when I look at the MSDN documentation on using SetWindowsHookEx.  Can someone please provide an example of how to use SetWindowsHookEx or another method of hooking into Windows?

Thank You

EDIT: I would like to note that I accepted the answer I did because it worked for me.  I could not use the other answer at the time the question was asked, but it looks like its just as good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short example from my own codebase which shows the most basic hooking technique:

```
unit MethodHooker;

interface

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Classes;

procedure Patch(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  NumberOfBytes: DWORD;
begin
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Address, @NewCode, Size, NumberOfBytes);
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure Redirect(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := Integer(NewAddress)-Integer(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  Patch(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

function GetCursorPos(var lpPoint: TPoint): BOOL; stdcall;
(* The GetCursorPos API in user32 fails if it is passed a memory address >2GB which
   breaks LARGEADDRESSAWARE apps.  We counter this by calling GetCursorInfo instead
   which does not suffer from the same problem. *)
var
  CursorInfo: TCursorInfo;
begin
  CursorInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(CursorInfo);
  Result := GetCursorInfo(CursorInfo);
  if Result then begin
    lpPoint := CursorInfo.ptScreenPos;
  end else begin
    lpPoint := Point(0, 0);
  end;
end;

initialization
  if not ModuleIsPackage then begin
    if not CheckWin32Version(6, 1) then begin
      //this bug was fixed in Windows 7
      Redirect(@Windows.GetCursorPos, @MethodHooker.GetCursorPos);
    end;

end.
```

Comment: Very nifty.  Can be used for evil, or for good.  But very nifty.

Comment: @mnuzzo Intel x86 documentation

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `$E9` also is compatible with Intel x64 processors, Windows 64 bits and x64 processes today?

Comment: @Sormanne It's not the processor that matters, or the OS version, rather the process architecture. A 32 bit process on a 64 platform is still a 32 bit process and executes in a 32 bit emulator, confusingly named WOW64. If you have a 64 bit process, then `$E9` is still fine so long as the relative address can fit in a signed 32 bit value.

Answer (score 5):

For a very good detouring/hooking unit (can check for jumps and apply new offset!) I would recommend [KOLdetours.pas](http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/trunk/SRC/KOLDetours.pas)

I use this in many projects, for example my AsmProfiler.

Btw: with detouring you get a "trampoline" so you can call the original function too!

Comment: +1 a unit like this (I'm familiar with madCodeHook) offers much more than my trivial example.

Comment: While your solution looks like its great, I can't use open source software.

Comment: @mnuzzo I don't think you mean that exactly. Perhaps you can't use code under MPL. But madCodeHook comes under a commercial licence, you ought to be able to use that.

Comment: @David I was referring to KOLdetours.pas which states at the top that it's from an open source project. I'll have to check what the procedure is for commercially licensed software.

Comment: @mnuzzo It's generally not the fact that code is open source that is the issue, it's usually the particular licence that constrains you.

Comment: @David I know. I also know that there's a negative connotation to OSS in the business world. I'd really rather not bring it up right now.

Comment: @mnuzzo Well, then you should consider paying Mathias Rauen for madCodeHook. Mathias is a superstar and his software is well worth any money you spend. All that said, you may be able to get by with my trivial code!

Comment: @David I think your code should get me by.  If it were my decision, I would go for madCodeHook, but I just started a few weeks ago and don't think I'm in a position to recommend it.  But if this type of thing becomes a recurring issue, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I am the auhtor of koldetours. The license is a free for all: i.e. use as you like EVEN IN COMMERCIAL PROGRAMS. Basically it is real open source, not crippled by any licensing. Just as the code from which it is derived. It clearly states so in the header.