# Delphi - change ribbon menu color when VCL theme is applied

Tags: delphi, styles, themes, ribbon, vcl

I'm using **TRibbon** on an Delphi XE7 application with **VCL theme** applied and I'd like to change the menu color (because it's difficult to see the items in dark themes), as following:

[image: with theme]

I've tried the following code, but it only works when style is disabled:

```
  Ribbon1.ApplicationMenu.Menu.ColorMap.MenuColor:= clYellow;
```

[image: without theme]

Also no effect with this line:

```
  Ribbon1.ApplicationMenu.Menu.ColorMap.MenuColor:= StyleServices.GetStyleColor(scButtonHot);
```

Does anyone know if it is possible?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try, I found a solution. I don't know if it's the best approach, but it worked for me and could be useful for someone else.

The problem is the method bellow (Vcl.ActnMenus.pas), when StyleServices is enabled:

```
procedure TCustomActionPopupMenu.DrawBackground;
begin
  inherited;
  if StyleServices.Enabled and not StyleServices.IsSystemStyle then
    StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tmPopupBackground),
      Rect(0, 0, Width, Height))
  else
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := ColorMap.MenuColor;
    Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  end;
end;
```

So, in order to bypass this method, I just hooked it (adapting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343922/hooking-a-dll-function-in-delphi)):

```
unit MethodHooker;

interface

uses Windows, Vcl.ActnMenus;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

  TCustomActionPopupMenu = class(Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionPopupMenu)
    procedure DrawBackgroundEx;
  end;

implementation

procedure Patch(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: NativeUInt);
var
  NumberOfBytes: NativeUInt;
begin
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Address, @NewCode, Size, NumberOfBytes);
end;

procedure Redirect(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := Integer(NewAddress)-Integer(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  Patch(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

{ TCustomActionPopupMenu }

procedure TCustomActionPopupMenu.DrawBackgroundEx;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color := $00EEEAE9;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
end;

initialization
  Redirect(@TCustomActionPopupMenu.DrawBackground, @TCustomActionPopupMenu.DrawBackgroundEx);

end.
```

That's it. Just save this unit and add it to the project. No need to call this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own style with the color you like.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But it's not the answer I was looking for. So no, It didn't help at all. There are several native dark themes and I don't want to create another one.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, to change a style, you have to create a new style starting from the one you like. Changing the colors of a styled control always pass by the style. You can change the style at runtime but that is not what you asked. See if [this link](https://www.tfzx.net/article/438459.html) would help you. The article has a lot of information, including links to other resources about styles. And when you'll look at documentation, remember you are using a rather old Delphi version.